# Double labels on x-axis for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using ggplot2 to plot two different discrete variables on the same graph, and the breaks I obtained for the two variables are obviously different. I would like to label the breaks on the x-axis with superimposed values of said labels, rather than next to one another, which I managed to do but did not really work on a small graph (labels overlapping).

This is the code I am using:

```
plot<-ggplot(data, aes(xcut,modx, group=1))+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(color="red"), se=F, linetype="dotted", size=1.25)+ 
  geom_line(data=data,aes(xcut,lowerx, color="red4"), size=1.5)+
  geom_line(data=data,aes(xcut,upperx, color="red4"), size=1.5)+
  geom_ribbon(data=data, aes(xcut,ymin=lowerx,ymax=upperx), fill="lightpink", alpha=0.4)+

  geom_smooth(data=databis, aes(xcut,modx, group=1, color="green"), se=F, linetype="dotted", size=1.25)+ 
  geom_line(data=databis,aes(xcut,upperx, color="green4"), size=1.5)+
  geom_line(data=databis,aes(xcut,lowerx, color="green4"), size=1.5)+
  geom_ribbon(data=databis, aes(xcut,ymin=lowerx,ymax=upperx), fill="chartreuse1", alpha=0.4)+

  ylim(min(data$lowerx,databis$lowerx),max(data$upperx,databis$upperx))+

  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Legend', 
                      values =c('red'='red','green'='green', 'green4'='green4', 'red4'='red4'), labels = c('','','',''))+
  scale_size_area() + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")+
  labs(title='')

plot<-plot + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1:10), labels=c(label6Ex$label))
```

I am sorry that I cannot provide a working example, due to the amount of data that would require. Basically I use the "x" variable, a related "modx" variable and a discrete variable "xcut" that is just "x" cut with ten breaks. I have two different dataframes (data and databis) where all variables have been similarly defined, but obviously the labels are different for both dfs. The labels I add in the end have been separately determined; as I said I have tried to add the two labels for each break as such:

```
plot<-plot + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1:10), labels=c(paste(labeldatax$label,labeldatabisx$label,sep=" - ")))
```

Which gives me this [graph for the x and xbis variables with both labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzDR2.png)

But it would be more convenient for me to have both labels superimposed vertically. Any help on the matter would be welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple... Thank you very much, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Superb! I reposted it as an answer so that you can close the question if that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `sep=" - "` by `sep="\n"`.